# Read console input via select function

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, file-descriptor

I'm trying to write program which uses sockets to send data over network. Now I need input commands from console. I have select function for sockets. In linux you can use select to look for data input in sockets and in conolse. How I can get same functionality on visual c++?

When I insert console descriptor in select function it returns error 10038 (Socket operation on nonsocket.)

Comment: Use a separate thread to read from the console.

Comment: I want to stay in one process

Comment: That's a noble desire, but is it backed by reason?

Comment: I don't know how to handle multiple threads, plus I have working program on linux right this way

Comment: Can you give me example? Or link to example?

Comment: Windows is not Linux. What works here does not necessarily works there. You need a different strategy for Windows. The strategy with a separate thread for console IO works. `select` is known not to work with console handles, `WaitFor...` is known not to work for sockets, and listening to Windows messages does not work too well in console applications. That's about all possible strategies out there.

Comment: I don't know what your program is supposed to do. Perhaps the easiest way to achieve maximum compatibility with the Linux version is to create an additional pair of sockets to emulate the terminal fd. Your console thread (or even a separate process, for simplicity) would read the console input and stuff it down one socket from the pair , and your main thread would `select` on the other half of the pair just like in Linux. I cannot give you a tutorial on threads here.

Comment: @n.m.: True that console handles can't be passed to `select` on Windows, but `WaitFor`... certainly can wait on socket activity, using `WSAEventSelect` as the glue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not support using `select` for arbitrary handles. In Linux and other forms of Unix, "all handles are equal", and it's not important whether they are handles for console, a socket or anything else.

Note that `select` in windows does not take a `HANDLE`, but a special `SOCKET` type of handle. See the definition of Windows' [`fd_set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The easiest solution is probably to use a second thread to read the console input. There is certainly no way to include the console into your `select` call. There may be ways to convince Windows that a `SOCKET` is a waitable object, and use it for something like [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), along with a console input handle - but I'm far from convinced (and I don't have a windows setup to try it out on).

Comment: I have created thread for accepting input from console. Worked.

Comment: The glue between `SOCKET` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` is `WSAEventSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ReadFile` with console `HANDLE`. So, you can read console as a file. You can also read from/write to sockets with `ReadFile` and `WrtieFile`
See MSDN docs for [Console Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Not sure this is what you want though. If you want some kind of `select` on windows you can take a look at [IO Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (not sure they work with console - check the docs)

Comment: On linux I can do this:
add socket and console decriptros to fd_set and use it in select function. On windwos when I try to do this I get errors

Comment: I afraid that there is no well supported UNIX API on Windows. So, unless you'll use something like MinGW/Cygwin, you wont't be able to do select call on windows. So, please read docs on IO Completion Ports - it's counterpart for UNIX poll/select, but somewhat twisted.